# inject method to class with decorator(or some other way)

Tags: python, oop, odoo, decorator

I have classes defined for ORM. I want override some method of it but because there is many classes of them i prefer somehow dynamically inject it.

```py
class Example(model.model):
    name = SomeField()
    lastname = SomeField()
    @framework.decorator
    def method_that_shows_fields(self):
        res = super(self).method_that_shows_fields()
        need_hide=['name']
        for i in need_hide:
          res[i]=False
        return False
```

I thought I could write decorator where I pass what I want

```py
def hide_decorator(*args):
    def inner(cls):
       def inner_fun(inst):
         return hid_func(inst)
       cls.method_that_shows_field= inner_fun
       return cls


     ...
@hide_decorator("name,lastname")
class Example:
   ...
```

There is some very bad example code but u got the details.

It is not working because of `super()` call needed in function and parent changes during that time.

Python gurus: any idea how would you do that?

Comment: can you try and explain a bit more? I can't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: framework called odoo frontend is automaticy generated. which data is show in here are determined by whos class methods. if you want hide some data you have to override them. but i have many classes. if i override all them it is just copy paste difference is only fields that needs to be hided. if i can somehow inject that method with parameter ,  it would be really good.

Comment: could you just have a class attribute `_need_hide` with list of field names to hide,  and then use from `method_that_shows_fields`?

Comment: i through about it, created NewClass inherited from base Model, and redefined method to use that  class attribute. but after everything breaks. for exampe base class had _name class attr used to set database name. but after  python tells me it has not found in parent.or maybe i made some mistake.

Comment: put your code in the question so we can see it